# How to screw in a screw that is nearly accessible?

Tags: walls, mounting

I have an antique coffee grinder and the plate is directly under the container.  What tool do I use

Comment: Hi and welcome here. It is hard to visualize what the issue is. Could you post a picture or two to show the details and how access is difficult.

Comment: That's not how the ancients built things.  Something else must come out.

Comment: If it is nearly accessible, then you shouldn't have an issue, do you mean nearly INaccessable? Smaller screw driver, 90 degree bend screwdriver, dissassemble more to get to it.... Where is the screw?Under the plate, or under the container?